# why float collapse does not arise with fixed position

Tags: html, css, css-float

I play with floats and I noticed then "float collapse bug" does not arise with fixed position. Here is [example](https://jsfiddle.net/1nq8b7xs/2/).

So I have two divs:

```
<body
    <div class="static">
        <img>
        <p>text text text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed">
        <img>
        <p>text text text</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

First with static position and second with fixed:

```
.fixed, .static{
    outline: 1px solid black;
    width: 150px;
}
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
}
img{
   float: right;
   background-color: green;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

And result:

[image: result]

So why the second fixed-div does not need something like `.clearfix` to fix float collapse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `position: fixed;` creates [Block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting).

Try the below styles also, which have similar effect in your `div`.

- `float`
- `position` `absolute` and `fixed`
- `display` - `inline-blocks`, `table`, `table-cells`
- `overflow` - `hidden`, `auto`

Answer (score 1):

if you want them both to appear the same you can put in `overflow-y:hidden;`

https://jsfiddle.net/1nq8b7xs/3/

or if you want them to appear beside each other use display:inline-block and remove position-fixed from your fixed class

https://jsfiddle.net/1nq8b7xs/4/

```css
.fixed, .static{
    outline: 1px solid black;
    width: 150px;
    overflow-y:hidden;  /*added this*/
}
.fixed{
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
}
img{
   float: right;
   background-color: green;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
.fixed, .static{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="static">
        <img>
        <p>text text text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed">
        <img>
        <p>text text text</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: And what if i want fixed-div to appear with float-collapse-bug?